# @app.route('/mybot',method=['POST']) AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'route'

Tags: python, flask

I am trying a flash application below is my code that i am following from tutorial

```
from flask import Flask, request
import requests
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse

app = (__name__)
@app.route('/mybot',methods=['POST'])
def mybot():
    incoming_message = request.values.get('Body','').lower()
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    msg = resp.message()
    responded = False
    if 'hi' in incoming_message:
        msg.body('Hello, iam luja')
        responded = True
    if 'quotes' in incoming_message:
        r = request.get('https://api.quotable.io/random')
        if r.status_code == 200:
            data = r.json()
            quote = f'{data["content"]}({data["author"]})'
        else:
            quote = 'not able to retrieve'
        
        msg.body(quote)
        responded = True
    if 'who are you' in incoming_message:
        msg.body('Hi i am Bot')
        responded = True
    if not responded:
        msg.body('not able to return the msg')
    
    return str(resp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I have installed all required dependancies. However when I run the code I get the above error, how can i resolve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change:

```
app = (__name__)
```

to:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

Otherwise app is assigned `__name__` which is a `str`, and as the error message says it does not have a `route` attribute.  In the latter case, app is assigned an instance of `Flask()` which does have the required `route` attribute.

Comment: I spelled it out further.  Let me know if it is not yet clear.